# int num = *(int *)number; What does this do?

Tags: c++, c, pointers

I was looking at some c++ code, and I saw this:

```
int num = *(int *)number;
```

I had never seen this before?
it was in a function labeled as such:

```
void *customer(void *number){ }
```

What does that even do? Is there a different way to show this?

Thanks, this isn't homework btw I was just confused at what this does?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The (int *) part casts the variable number to a pointer to an int, then the * in front dereferences it to an int.

Comment: +1 @Charles yep, basically num will now hold a copy of the value that number was pointing to.

Comment: Worthwhile to add: While casting FROM void pointer, we need to use the cast operators.This is the reason of using (int *) which casts 'number' which is pointer to void, to a pointer to an int. And * further deference this pointer to an int to return an int.

Answer (score 17):

The function takes a `void*`, but somehow it knows (perhaps it's required in some documentation somewhere) that the pointer it's given actually points to an `int`.

So, `(int*)number` is "the original pointer, converted to an `int*` so that I can read an `int` from it", and `*(int*)number` is the int value that it points to.

Answer (score 6):

The correct answers are already here, but can I tell you a trick that generally helped me when I had to use C a lot?

It's how you pronounce "*" in your head--and there are two parts.

The common part is when it is part of a type--and everybody probably says "pointer" when they read that, which is great.  So (int *) is an int pointer--or I'll even reverse it in my head to read "pointer to an int" which seems to help a little.

The thing that helps a lot for me is whenever you see * in your code--read it as "what is pointed to by".

If you follow this pattern, then:

```
int num = *(int *)number;
```

is an integer variable "num" gets assigned the value: what is pointed to by an int pointer, number.  It just translates itself.

Sometimes you have to mess with the phrasing a little, but since I got into that habit I've never had a big problem reading pointer code.

I believe I also read & as "The address of" in C, but I think it's been overloaded in C++ if I recall correctly.

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming `customer` is used like this:

```
int lookup = 123;
customer_key *key = customer(&lookup);
// do something with key here
```

In which case, the code in customer is typecasting the `void *` to an `int *` and then dereferencing it (getting its value). It has to typecast first because `void *` basically means "pointer to something", which allows you to pass in any type you want. Without the typecast the compiler doesn't know if you want to read a `char` (usually 1 byte), a `short` (usually 2 bytes) or an `int` (usually 4 bytes). The typecast removes the ambiguity.

Note using `void *` for the argument is probably not the best, since you could do:

```
double lookup = 69.0f;
customer_key *key = customer(&lookup);
```

And this will compile, but won't look up customer 69 (a `double` is not an `int`!).

The use of `void *` may be intentional, the code may be able to determine (hopefully safely) between pointers and an argument like: `(void *)3` - which would be a special case.

Answer (score 1):

The function accepts a void pointer (thus void *). In order to dereference it to a variable of a certain type (e.g. int) - which is what teh first "*" does - you need to cast it to a pointer to an actual type  - in this case to an int pointer via (int *) cast

Answer (score -1):

```
int num = *(int *)number;
```

typically, 'number' here should be a pointer with some type, usually a `void*` pointer.

`(int *)number`, means you cast the original type to `int*`, and `*(int *)number`, means you get the value of int pointer.