# What does *(int *) variable = value mean?

Tags: c

I am reading the online book [Object-Oriented Programming with ANSCI-C](https://www.cs.rit.edu/%7Eats/books/ooc.pdf)

Page 6 shows an implementation of a `set`. There is an `add()` function that takes two parameters: a `set` and an `element`. The `element` is added to the `set`. The implementation uses an array of pointers:

```
static int heap [MANY];
```

Here is the beginning of the `add()` function:

```
void * add (void * _set, const void * _element)
{ 
    int * set = _set;
    const int * element = _element;

    if (* element == MANY)
        * (int *) element = set — heap;
```

It is that last line:

```
* (int *) element = set — heap;
```

that I do not understand. It appears that the right-hand side is subtracting pointers, is that right? Is that common to subtract pointers? On the left-hand side it appears that `(int *)` is casting `element` to a "pointer to an int", is that right? The star at the beginning appears to indicate "the value of the thing being pointed at", is that right?

Sorry, I am lost. What is the code saying?

**Update (a question based on the responses)**

Thank you for the outstanding responses!

I have a follow-up question about this expression: `set - heap`

`heap` is the name of an array. `set` is one of the cells in `heap`, say, `heap[2]`. So, the expression is subtracting the pointer to `heap` from the pointer to `heap[2]`, is that right? I used a `printf()` statement to output `heap` and output `set`, here's what it output:

```
heap = 4227136
set  = 4227140
```

So, `set - heap` equals `4`. Does that mean `set` is pointing at `heap[4]` (i.e., `4` cells from the start of the array)? Is the pointer to `heap[i+1]` always guaranteed to be `1` more than the pointer to `heap[i]`?

I output the value of `element` after this statement was executed:

```
* (int *) element = set — heap;
```

As just discussed, the value of `set - heap` is `4`. The output says the value of `element` is `1`. How can that be, shouldn't the value of `element` be `4`?

Comment: `* (int *) element` is a **cast** and **dereference** at first `element` is cast to `int *` (which is casting away the `const` qualifier to `element`) and then it is a dereference of the `int *` pointer resulting in `int` to which the assignment is made. The pointer is constant but the memory location isn't , so it is fine here.

Comment: This may help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4170249/int-num-int-number-what-does-this-do

Generally, (int *) casts the element to a pointer to an `int`, then the * in front dereferences it to an `int`

Comment: @Roger Costello I am sure that the book is bad.:)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since `*element` is a `const int`, it can't directly be assigned.

So the cast

```
    * (int *) element = set — heap;
```

converts `element` to `int *` and then dereferences, then assigns the result of `set - heap`.

However, this is only valid if:

- the original object that `_element` points to is a modifiable object. Otherwise, casting away the `const` is undefined behaviour.
- that points to an `int` object.

Yes, `set - heap` is subtracting two pointers. But it could be invalid because:

- the result of subtracting two pointer yields a `ptrdiff_t` which may or may not fit in an `int` type.
- the subtraction is only valid if the two pointers point to the same array object or one past the last element of the array object. See [6.5.6 Additive operators/9](https://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.5.6p9)

In summary, the code does what you're alluding to with your questions. But it needs to meet the conditions noted above to be valid.

Answer (score 3):

> It appears that the right-hand side is subtracting pointers, is that right?

Yes

> Is that common to subtract pointers?

Yes

> On the left-hand side it appears that (int *) is casting element to a "pointer to an int", is that right?

Yes. The reason to do that is to override the `const` qualifier. This is a VERY dangerous thing to do.

> The star at the beginning appears to indicate "the value of the thing being pointed at", is that right?

Yes